# Unable to fetch server IP in openstack VM

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, openstack

I have a windows instance running in openstack, named `vm-name`.
I executed the following code to fetch the details of the VM:

```
$vmName = "vm-name"
$url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8774/v2.1/servers?name=$vmName"
# $headers have the API token

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $headers
```

The result, `$response` is supposed to also return the `server.addresses` field, but it only has the fields `id`, `links`, and `name`. `links` contain two urls, termed self and bookmark in the format `http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8774/v2.1/servers/id`.
Any idea on how to get the server URL?. I am able to see the IP via openstack UI console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network details can not be fetched by `/servers` endpoint.

To get the IP address use the following:

```
$url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8774/v2.1/servers/$serverId/ips"
# $headers have the API token

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $headers
$response.addresses
```

`$serverId` can be fetched from the rest call in the question.